# Geocoder gem not working live with Heroku. Why this fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The geocoder gem was not working for me once I pushed my app to heroku, only when running on my localhost.

I added `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to application.rb and now it is working. Can someone please tell me why this is so and if there are any consequences I may run into resulting from this.